# Ошибки при вызове WinAPI из Visual Basic

Tags: winapi, visual-basic

В проекте VB6 получаю такую ошибку:

> Can`t find entry point DdeGetDataA in user32

В коде:

```
Pulic Declare Function DdeGetData Lib "user32" Alias "DdeGetDataA" (ByVal hData As Long,  pDst As Byte, ByVal cbMax As Long, ByVal cbOff As Long) As Long
Public Function DdeCallback(ByVal wType As Long, ByVal fmt As Integer, ByVal hConv As Long, ByVal hsz1 As Long, ByVal hsz2 As Long, ByVal hData As Long, ByVal dwData1 As Long, ByVal dwData2 As Long) As Long
Select Case (wType)
Case 16528
        Dim Result As Long
        ReDim pSrc_t(0 To 9999)
        Result = DdeGetData(hData, pSrc_t(0), 10000, 0)
End Select
End Function
```

Уже 3 часа парюсь, не могу понять, где собака зарылась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалил Alias "DdeGetDataA" и всё заработало! Почему!?

Comment: Наверное потому, что в user32.dll отсутствует точка входа DdeGetDataA, но присутствует DdeGetData

Comment: Viewer API предложил строку с алиасом, а он обычно не ошибается...